# Older Ruby Version Showing After Installing Latest One

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I am following the instructions on [GoRails](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite#ruby) to install Ruby & Rails on my system. After following the instructions for installing Ruby using rbenv, I verified the ruby version is **2.1.3**.

However, upon opening a new terminal the ruby version defaults back to **2.0.0** unless I execute `rbenv global 2.1.3`.

Could someone please explain how I can have this rectified?

Comment: whats the content of `~/.rbenv/version`, and is the RBENV_VERSION environment variable set?

Comment: Can you post the output from the following commands: `which ruby` `which rbenv` `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: @PeteyT `~/.rbenv/version` returns `Command not found`. How can I check the RBENV_VERSION environment variable?

Comment: @DavidAntaramian you need to view the contents of `~/.rbenv/version` not run it as a command. `cat ~/.rbenv/version`. To see if the env variable is set you run `echo $RBENV_VERSION`.

Comment: @DavidAntaramian I have taken the outputs [here](https://gist.github.com/frmuses/8337575880a3f117fc7c)

I am providing outputs for ruby 2.0.0 and ruby 2.1.3

Comment: @PeteyT here you go
`➜  ~  echo $RBENV_VERSION

➜  ~  cat ~/.rbenv/version
2.1.3`

Comment: @PeteyT He installed rbenv using the homebrew package manager, so it's going to be under /usr/local/var/rbenv/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try doing the following

```
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Then open a new shell.

The tutorial you used assumed your shell was bash, but you are using zsh. You need to modify .zshrc instead of .bash_profile.

Comment: Thanks @DavidAntaramian that nailed it. Will keep this in mind in future installations.

Comment: If it solved the issue for you, would you mind marking my answer as correct? Thanks