# Ruby version showing 2 although Ruby 3 installed

Tags: ruby

I am currently using ruby version 2.7.0 and I want to upgrade to version 3.1.0 in ubuntu 20:04. I have installed ruby 3.1.0 by following [Install ruby 3 using rbenv](https://richstone.io/where-is-ruby-3-0-0-on-rbenv/). This is my output of command rbenv versions, seems the installation is completed.

```
peisen@peisen:~$ rbenv versions
* system (set by /home/peisen/.rbenv/version)
  3.1.0
```

However, when i check my ruby version using ruby -v

```
peisen@peisen:~$ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

It shows the version is still 2.7.0. I am still a beginner in ubuntu and not sure how to modify this. I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769822/older-ruby-version-showing-after-installing-latest-one) but this did not work for me. Any ideas?

Comment: `rbenv global 3.1.0` should do it, the asterisk symbol shows that the ruby version being used is the system version (which is 2.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output

```
peisen@peisen:~$ rbenv versions
* system (set by /home/peisen/.rbenv/version)
  3.1.0
```

means that you have two versions installed, system Ruby and 3.1.0. The asterisk indicates that system Ruby is still the currently selected version.

To switch to Ruby 3.1.0 globally run:

```
$ rbenv global 3.1.0
```

See the docs about [`rbenv global`](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-global) and other options to set your desired Ruby version.